# Deploy WAR to Single JVM out of cluster (JBoss EAP 7)

Tags: jboss-eap-7

We have setup JBoss EAP 7 in domain mode with one server group and 2 JVM's.

Server Group A --> Server1 & Server 2.

Is there any way we can deploy a war file to just one Server? (Not to the cluster)

Test1.war --> Server1
Test2.war --> Server2

Comment: I think you can just deploy it to a single server as "unmanaged" - that might allow it to not follow the identical configuration domain model, e.g. it wouldn't be added to the config xml - it would just be deployed like things used to be in JBoss EAP 5 and lower

Comment: I don't think it's possible,as deployment is done on a server-group completely(Applies to all the servers in a server-group).If you want to deploy it on a single server you can go ahead and create an individual server-group containing just this one server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that is possible.

All servers in a server group are supposed to have identical configurations, so having a deployment not applied to all servers in a group would break that.

Of course, you could create another server group (even if it only contains one server) if you wanted a different configuration for a particular server.